# Popup-model is not opening in for loop (HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-templates

I am trying to open a `Pop up Model` in `for loop` for every instance but the `pop up model` is opening for first instance But is not opening for other instances. I am using `Django` in template loop.

template.html

```
{% for comment in comments %}

    <button id="ModelButton">Open Model</button>
    <div id="Model" class="flagModel">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-mod">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %} 
                            {{form}}
                            <input type="submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
    var formModel= document.getElementById("Model");
    var formButton = document.getElementById("ModelButton");
    formButton .onclick = function () {
      formModel.style.display = "block";
    }
    window.onclick = function (event) {
      if (event.target == formModel) {
        formModel.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
</script>

{% endfor %}
```

When I Place the `JavaScript` outside the `for loop` then it doesn't even work for one.

I have tried many times but it is still not working. Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You

Comment: You must not use id in a loop

Comment: You mean i should use `class` instead of `id` to make this work ?

Comment: Yes, I will prefer to use class and change in script as well

Comment: But when i use `document.getElementByClassName` then the model is not even opening outside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify unique IDs to the modals and pass the id number to a single function to open form modals on click of their respective buttons.

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    <button onclick="openModal({{forloop.counter}})">
        Open Model
    </button>

    <div id="Modal-{{forloop.counter}}" class="flagModel">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-mod">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %} 
                        {{form}}
                        <input type="submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

<script>
    function openModal(id) {
        var formModal = document.getElementById(`Modal-${id}`);
        if (formModal) {
            formModal.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
    
    window.onclick = function (event) {
      if (event.target == formModel) {
        formModel.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The id should be unique on a page, you should use class in loop instead of id,

Here I have updated your script that may help you

```
{% for comment in comments %}

    <button class="ModelButton">Open Model</button>
    <div class="flagModel Model">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-mod">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %} 
                            {{form}}
                            <input type="submit">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
    var formButton = document.querySelectorAll(".ModelButton");
    formButton.forEach(function(element) {
      element.addEventListener('click', function(eventObj) {
        var formModel = eventObj.currentTarget.nextElementSibling;
        formModel.style.display = "block";
        formModel.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
          eventObj.currentTarget.style.display = "none";
        });
      })
    });
    
</script>

{% endfor %}
```